# Can't assign value to global variable, usin Volley to request (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio

```
        JsonObjectRequest requestM = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, moveUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    typeVariable = response.getJSONObject("type").getString("name");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out.println("catch ERROR");
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("Listener ERROR");
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(requestM);
        return typeVariable;
    }
```

typeVariable is defined in class fields, typeVariable is assigned correctly inside try (have checked) but this method still returns null.

I am still a begginer so I'm probably doing something stupid.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You *can* set it to a global variable, but it's asynchronous; you have no way of knowing when the value is actually filled with the response. Here you return it before the request completes.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! How can i know when the request is over?

Comment: When `onResponse` or the error listener runs. Bigger picture: there's a lot of async stuff in programming; you'll need to wrap your head around some of that.